# BinarySearchTree isBalanced method not working

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Hello here is my isBalanced method and the appropriate helpers.

```
 public boolean isBalanced() {
      return isBalancedHelper(root);
  }

  public boolean isBalancedHelper(Node node) {
      if(node == null) {
          return true;
      }

      int heightDif = height(node.left) - height(node.right);
      if(Math.abs(heightDif) > 1) {
          return false;
      }
      else {
          return isBalancedHelper(node.left) && isBalancedHelper(node.right);
      }
  }

  public int height(Node node) {
      if(node == null) {
          return 0;
      }
      return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right));
  }
```

I don't have the tests that it is failing because it's in an autograder but the output message says this.

isBalanced() returns true when left child is non-null and right is null.

I've been looking at this for a while and can't figure out why this isn't working. Any suggestions?